# Should RF output of (30+j10) Ohms be matched to 50Ohms for antenna matching network?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, esp32

I'm designing a matching network for a 2.4GHz inverted F antenna. I am using an ESP32-D0WDQ6 MCU, and reading from the datasheet, the output impedance for the RF pins is (30+j10) Ohms. ([DATASHEET](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) in section 2.5 on page 7)

Should the matching network be set to 50 Ohms? Or should it be set at (30+j10) Ohms?

EDIT: anyone reading this should read the further comments with Andy AKA's answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your antenna is 50 Ω and your source is 30 Ω  + j10 Ω then, add a series capacitor of -j10 Ω to cancel out the +j10 Ω effect of the inductor.

This now means you are trying to match 30 Ω resistive to an antenna of 50 Ω resistive.

Then use an L-pad calculator like [**this**](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html): -

[image]

You can double check the formula derivation on that site.

- Series inductance needs to be about 1.6 nH
- Parallel capacitance needs to be about 1.1 pF

Then, if you went back to the start of the problem and analysed what value of inductance is needed to produce the j10 Ω in your driver output impedance, you'd calculate it to be 0.663 nH at 2.4 GHz.

This means that you can actually dispense with the added series capacitor of -j10 Ω (as originally proposed) because you need 1.624 nH from the above calculator. The upshot of this is that 1.624 nH might as well be 1.663 nH so, the external series inductor you need to add is 1 nH.

Comment: Thank you for that. If I'm designing a microstrip IFA antenna on a simulator, without simulating the matching network, should I set the antenna impedance as close as possible to 30Ω + j10Ω position on the smith chart? And then just match to 30Ω + j10Ω looking into the antenna on a VNA in real life with the probe positioned before the matching network? Or set ant imp to 50Ω on smith chart in simulator? I will b designing the antenna, so the only reason I bring up 50Ω is because I thought it might b more ideal due to 50Ω normally being the best compromise between low attenuation & power handling

Comment: To be complete, I meant when saying "Or set ant imp to 50Ω on smith chart in simulator?", set antenna impedance at 2.4GHz to 50Ω position on the smith chart in simulator, then in real life match to 30Ω + j10Ω (as you mentioned) looking into the antenna on a VNA with the probe positioned before the matching network?

Comment: If you are not wanting to use matching components you set the antenna to be 30 - j10 to maximise power from a 30 + j10 source but, only if you are not creating a transmission line to connect them i.e. the connection distance is very short.

Comment: My transmission line length is less than 1/4 wavelength & more than 1/8, and I'm fine with using matching components. Wouldn't it b more ideal 2 use them, even w/ short line? And should I set the excitation port impedance setting on the simulator to 30Ω + j10Ω or 50Ω, & set the antenna to be 30 - j10, or 50Ω? How would I write that as a single impedance 4 the simulator without the imaginary j? If I'm using matching components, should the antenna always b 50Ω, and matching network at 30Ω - j10Ω? I have my transmission line from IC to ANT set to 50Ω. Just looking 4 most ideal way 2 do everything

Comment: Also my excitation port on the simulator is currently set at 50 Ohms.

Comment: Set the antenna to 50ohms, its most common. Primary reason is because if you have any transmission line at all it will typically be 50 ohms, so you want to use that value to make ease of everything matching

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question based on your recent comments. Training and teaching is limited (very) in comments and I particularly shy away from that so, compose your new thoughts and ask a new question. Leave me a comment so that I am reminded when I start work tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll do that.

Comment: @wdbwbd1 I didn't see any new question so maybe I missed it? Are we done with this question now or is there something particularly relevant that I may have missed?

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I've just been really busy, I intend to make a new one soon and I will notify you when I do. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well, if you’ve finished with this question, you should formally accept the most relevant answer @wdbwbd1

Comment: Actually I'm realizing this may be all I need, but first after removing L components on PCB should I trim the length of my IFA antenna on the PCB until it measures nearest to 50 Ω measured on a VNA at antenna input as in this pic? https://imgur.com/RbECVR1

I plan on setting the antenna to 50 Ω in the simulator, but drawing it on the PCB with a longer length arm that I will trim to reach nearest to 50 Ω on the actual PCB so it's exact. Is this the right strategy? 
Then this is the finished circuit? https://imgur.com/mMQYV32

And 50 Ω transmission line is optimal from RF pin to L network?

Comment: And what if the antenna doesn't match perfectly to 50 ohms? Normally I believe with a 50 ohm source and 50 ohm antenna, if the antenna isn't exactly 50 ohms then the matching network adjusts for that to match source using custom component values, but if the L pad Network is just changing 30 ohms to 50 ohms instead, that seems to remove the ability to match the antenna to 50 ohms if needed. Is this correct, and how is this addressed?

Comment: You should probably be aware that this is a q and a site and not a forum where we deal with an evolving scenario of questions or try and train folk in an evolutionary way. You ask a question and, somebody provides an answer. This site is basically a good reference gallery of good questions and good answer. Having said that a certain amount of diversity is tolerated but, in my humble opinion, we are done withe the basic q and a and, you should formulate your new stuff into a new question @wdbwbd1

Comment: Ok, best answer given and I'll let you know when I post the new question, might not be today. Thanks again.

Comment: If the antenna drive impedance became 50 ohms then, with the current matching network, it won't make a big deal. The reflection coefficient of 50 ohms with a base of 30 ohms is (50-30)/(50+30) = 0.25 so, in effect there is a 25% power loss. That's probably not a big deal provided that reflections and standing waves aren't a big deal. I think that's the bottom line @wdbwbd1 because your t-line length I think you said was quite small.

Comment: Thanks, I would rather keep reflections and power loss to an absolute minimum. 25% is more than I would like. I posted a new question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543823/how-to-match-rf-output-of-30j10-ohms-to-50-ohm-antenna-with-matching-network

Answer (score 1):

The antenna may be 50 ohms but you need to check the specs on it. You definitely want to match the antenna so yes you probably want a matching network between the pin and antenna, fire up an Pi matching network app or webpage and type in the parameters to get values back out the you need to match

The datasheet you shared said yes you need a Pi matching network. So im not sure why you are asking, but yes you want 50 ohms out, but like 30-j10 on the input of the Pi network to match the mcu pin (notice the negative j30)

Comment: I understand a matching network is required. My question was "Should the matching network be set to 50 Ohms? Or should it be set at (30+j10) Ohms?" Looking into the antenna, should I match to the (30+j10) Ohms point on the smith chart to match the IC, or should I match to the center of the smith chart at 50 Ohms which is normally ideal for transmission lines? What do you mean by "you want 50 ohms out, but like 30-j10 on the input of the Pi network"?

Comment: I was wondering if 50 ohms might be more ideal due to normally being the best compromise between low attenuation and power handling.

Comment: You want a matching Pi network that is 30-j10 on the input and 50 ohms on the output. Remember, if you see a J, you want to compenstate and "tune out the j". The chip is +j10 which means you need to "cancel that out" with a -j10 to leave behind only the 30 (30 ohms). If the Pi network does this it will match to the mcu pin exactly. The Pi can have a different input and output impedance, that is its job, so you match on input of the Pi with 30-j10 and simply match the out with 50 (no j)